# External mic detected but no sound produced

Tags: audio, dell-inspiron, microphone

I have a Dell Inspiron 1525 laptop. I randomly get this issue recently where my mic, when plugged in, does not produce any sound. I used to get a pop up prompt when I would plug in a headset/mic, but that doesn't happen anymore either. The mic does appear in the plugged in "Sound devices" though, when I open the window. Sound is not produced on Skype nor any of my computer's own recording devices. The internal mic is still functional (though I don't like using it because it has poor sound quality and I always have to be right in front of and near the laptop screen or else I'm not heard well).

- I tried another microphone I had and even bought a brand new one, and still nothing.
- Yes it is set as the default sound device, and yes it is definitely not muted.
- I tried updating the drivers as well.

I Skype daily so this is very inconvenient. What's suddenly happened to my computer?